# Kafka server not starting on windows, kafka-server-start.bat returning no output

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

Please help me in making Kafka server up and run, I could able to run zookeeper perfectly fine but when I run `kafka-server-start.bat D:\Kafka\config\Server.properties` command console returning no output.

Note: I have changed `log.dirs` to my local folder.

[Kafka- Command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKSyc.png)

Here is server.properties configuration

```
broker.id=0
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=D:\kafka\kafkalogs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

Comment: can you share the contents of your log file ?

Comment: Hi radai, there is no log file generated in that folder, folder is empty

Answer (score 7):

I found the problem, it was due to missing `C:\Windows\System32` in the environment path of the system variable, after adding below including wbem, it resolves the issue. Thanks!

%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32;SystemRoot%

Comment: I already have these paths in my environment path variable. but it doesn't work. Can please tell me another solution to this problem.

Comment: For me, this worked, make sure to add all 3

Comment: Thanks, @coder, This solution worked well for me. To be more concise we need to add `C:\Windows\System32` in a path of System Variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run the `.bat` file correctly (note the `.` in the beginning):

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem and for me the cause was the JAVA_HOME Windows environment variable pointing to a JRE and not a JDK.

I updated the environment variable in the control panel to point to a Java 8 JDK and Kafka started working.

Attention: for some reason setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable in the .bat file or at command line level did not work, I had to set it using the Windows Control Panel.